# Unable to get path of CD Drive in SaveFileDialog

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, path

I have a SaveFileDialog that works as expected except for the case when the user selects a CD Drive with a disc in it that has already been formatted and written to at least once(it works as expected when the disc has not been written to yet). In the case when the disc hasn't been written to, the path returned by the dialog is the default windows waiting to be burn folder which is fine. However, you get an error whenever the disc in the CD Drive has been written too. Why can't the SaveFileDialog just give me the same path everytime regardless of the state of the disc in the CD Drive. More Importantly, how can I get around this? [image]

Comment: Is the disk CD-R or CD-RW?

Comment: Is your CD rewritable?

Comment: It needs to work for any disc type RW and Non-RW discs. I just want to be able to get the path of the drive I select, which is the whole object of the SaveFileDialog. To answer your question its a CD-R.

Comment: The disc type shouldn't matter, I would think. The reason for this form is to get a path.

Comment: I am not sure if you should use `SaveFileDialog` at all for this. What do you want to do with the path if you do not want to save s.th. to this path?

Comment: Are you sure you don't want FolderBrowserDialog?

Comment: I agree 100%. However, I'm working with code where making a change like this will require substantially more work then just coming up with a fix for whats already integrated into the code. If there is no other way I guess the FolderBrowserDialog is the way to go?